# Service Pattern in Spring may be more efficient with state

Tags: java, spring, optimization, service, singleton

So I'm relatively new to Spring and I'm trying to fully understand the service pattern and the DAO/entity patterns.  In general I have the Entity (for Hibernate), the DAO which implements the CRUD using the entity and then the service objects that interacts with the DAO (Correct me if I'm wrong to this point, that's very likely).

I understand that services should be stateless so they can be implemented as a singleton for autowiring and dependency injection.  However, I have an instance where a service may be made more efficient by maintaining state.

Let's say I have the following entity (not my actual entity):

```
@Entity
public class entity {
    private int id;
    private String category;
    private String value;
}
```

My service needs to pull these entities, and then for each endpoint in my controller, I need to look for an entity whose category matches "ABC" and whose value "X" occurs in a large string.  Since I don't have "X" at runtime, I can't just issue a request "where category = 'ABC' and value = 'X'".  Instead, I have to pull all entities "where category = 'ABC'" and see if their value is in my string.

So far I have come up with the following solutions:

- Have the service pull *all* entities out of the database at instantiation, and then when I need to see if my string contains the value for any entities whose category is "ABC" , I search through the list checking the category and then see if my `string.contains(entity.value)`.  The downside here is that the entities are set at instantiation, so if updates occur to the database after instantiation it won't pick them up.  This is also "stateful", so kind of breaks the service "stateless" rule.
- Have the service pull *only* entities with category "ABC" every time I need them, and then loop over the result looking to see if my `string.contains(entity.value)`.  This seems better, but the downside here is that I may need to make multiple calls for the same category in the same endpoint, so I'm pulling every single entity for category "ABC" multiple times, resulting in extra trips to the database.
- Have the service provide a method `List<entity> getList(String category)` to return a list of all entities with category "ABC", and then another method `entity searchList(List<entity> entities, String str)` that checks each entity to see if it is contained in str.  Then the endpoint could retrieve the List in the beginning of execution, and run `searchList` every time it needed to check.  The problem here is I feel like this is putting too much responsibility on the point of the calling code to maintain that state.
- Throw out the singleton pattern and instantiate a new object and call `getList` one time with category "ABC" which would give me one database trip per endpoint.  The object would keep the list as its state and every call to `searchList` would iterate only over the list I retrieved at the beginning.  The downside here is that it couldn't be autowired.

How do I do something like that in a service without maintaining state?  Am I "over-pattern-izing" it?  Should I just make a "non-service" object to handle this?  Would this be a good candidate for a prototype scope?

Comment: can´t you just make your query something like " (... ) where category = 'ABC' and value like '%X%' " ?

Comment: No, that's backwards.  I need to see if "X" is in my string that's constructed at runtime, not the other way around.

Comment: When is "value" be set and where? How often are the entities updated during the application lifetime?

Comment: Those are set in the database during configuration.  Entities are *probably* not updated during the application lifetime, so it wouldn't be very dangerous to instantiate all at once and maintain state.  In fact, if entities are being updated, there's most likely a recompile coming.

Comment: @zeusalmighty this situation (data doesn't change very often) is what caching is for: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: A particular advantage (over your other ideas) is you can just switch the caching off in the tests.

Comment: I think that'll provide me exactly what I need.  Can you propose this as an answer?

Comment: So I tried this last night.  I didn't mention a caveat that I thought was irrelevant but turns out to be so.  When I find a match, I need to throw an error.  That can't be cached. :(  I tried two methods; one to cache the set from the database and the other to iterate over the result set and throw an error if it found one.  Turns out, however that the @Cacheable annotation does not apply when methods call inside the same class.  It looks like I need to do some gymnastics to make that work.